# How to increase volume beyond 100% on Kubuntu KDE

Tags: kde, audio-volume

I'm using Kubuntu and need to increase my volume beyond 100% on many youtube videos, because the recording level was too low, and my speaker is capable of generating much louder volume.

Comment: this is a reasonable idea (volume compression) - `pavucontrol` can do it. Just to check though - have you checked the volume button next to the "play" button on youtube?  On crunchyroll, there's this stupid volume button that I seem to have repeatedly clicked without realizing it, just one click is enough to set a random volume, so I'm wondering if you've managed to do something similar on Youtube.

Comment: I've checked Youtube volume, KDE's volume, and the Speaker Volume.  There is a series of tutorials I'm watching from a particular publisher, and they recorded the series with too low of an input from the mic, apparently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile -vcodec copy -af "volume=10dB" outputfile
```

would increase volume by 10dB

VLC allows you to watch a network stream, you enter a youtube URL and you can increase the volume to 125% - I read to 200%.

Comment: Is there a way to amplify the sound real time, as it streams from the Internet as Youtube does?

Comment: I believe there is you need to look at sox IIRC.

Comment: But VLC will take you a long way and with much less hassle.